# How to find the output of this problem using R

Tags: r

Here is the data

```
ID  Month   Sal
1   1       70
2   1       10
3   1       30
1   2       60
2   2       90
3   2       50
1   3       80
2   3       40
3   3       20
```

How do I find what is the max salary for each ID and what is the respective month?

I tried using aggregate for the max salary but how to find the respective month for each ID when he got the max salary

Comment: @akrun I did not read your original comment, so not exactly sure what you mean. Just marked it so future users find the link. Although without an appropriate title to this question, that might not happen anyway.

Comment: @akrun please stop discussing things that are not relevant to this post; if you want to discuss other posts: do it there

Answer (score 1):

We can `group_by` the 'ID' and `slice` the row with the `max` 'Sal'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    slice(which.max(Sal))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Month   Sal
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     3    80
#2     2     2    90
#3     3     2    50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Month = c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Sal = c(70L, 10L, 30L, 60L, 
 90L, 50L, 80L, 40L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -9L))
```